# Why is [Timestamp] column in EF core backed by byte[] column instead of UInt64

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, ef-core-2.0

When using a timestamp column in Entity Framework it is backed by `rowversion` column type in SQL Server and represented as CLR's `byte[]` (according to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/concurrency)). The column has length of 8 bytes.

Why they decided to use `byte[]` instead of `UInt64`? It would hold the value just fine. Are there any non-obvious benefits of using byte[] or is it just for use of EF with other DB engines, which could implement rowversion-like column as different data type internally.

Comment: *other DB engines, which could implement rowversion-like column as different data type internally.* Isn't this reason more than enough? :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The purpose of the rowversion/timestamp field is that every time it updates, it is a new unique value.  The fact that for some implementations it is a 'timestamp' is irrelevant.

According to [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/rowversion-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), for MS-SQL it is an incrementing number, according to [this page](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-timestamp.aspx), for MySql it is a timestamp.

Therefore an array of 'bytes' makes the most sense compatibility wise.